# Access is denied when using Invoke-Command in Powershell

Tags: powershell

When i run

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName NY-TRAINING -ScriptBlock { Start-Process '\\Ny-wnorales\c$\CitrixReceiver 4.10.exe' }
```

i get an Access is denied error message 
I have even tried it with 
[image]

Comment: Sounds like a classic [Double Hop Problem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/knowledgecast/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem/) to me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround (looks like a double-hop problem as @EBGreen points out):

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
Invoke-Command -ComputerName NY-TRAINING -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock {
    $Drive = @{
        Name = 'Remote'
        PSProvider = 'FileSystem'
        Root = '\\Ny-wnorales\C$'
        Credential = $using:Credential
    }
    New-PSDrive @Drive
    Start-Process -FilePath 'Remote:\CitrixReceiver 4.10.exe' -Credential $using:Credential
}
```

Comment: No Access is still denied, I can run this command on the training computer
Start-Process \\NY-WNORALES\C$\CitrixReceiver 4.10.exe'  and it works